# Questions regarding the weak closure of the unit sphere being the unit ball.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reviewing a well established results that in infinite dimensional Banach space $B$ the weak closure of the the unit sphere is the unit ball. I am following a proof from Kesavan's *Functional Analysis* and I get everything up until he claims that showing every weakly open neighborhood of every point in the open unit ball intersects the unit sphere **implies** the closed unit ball must
lie in the weak closure of the unit sphere. Could someone please elaborate on this part of the proof.

PS: I don't think it is necessary, but I can provide the whole proof if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basic point-set topology. The closure of a set $X$ (in a certain topology, such as the weak topology here) is the intersection of all closed sets containing $X$, or equivalently the complement of the union of all open sets that don't intersect $X$.

If a point $a$ is not in the closure of $X$, that means there's an open set containing $a$ (namely the complement of the closure of $X$) that doesn't intersect $X$. By the contrapositive, if every open set containing $a$ intersects $X$, then $a$ is in the closure of $X$. Done.